# How do I combine GPS track data with another time-coded dataset?

Tags: mapping, gps, gis, kml

I have GPS track data from a logging device, in GPX format (or any other format, easily done with gpsbabel). I also have non-GPS data from another measurement device over the same time period. However, the measurement intervals of both devices are not synced.
Is there any software available that can combine the measurement data with the GPS data, so I can plot the measured values in a spatial context?
This would require matching of measurement times and interpolation of GPS trackpoints, combining the results in a new track file.

I could start scripting all of this, but if there are existing tools that can do this, I'd be happy to know about them. I was thinking that GPSBabel might be able to do this, but I haven't found how.

Answer (score 0):

a simple Excel Macro would do your job

Comment: I was hoping for a software tool that would do this for me... But it seems scripting is the way to go, indeed. Although it will be Python in my case :-)

Answer (score 0):

In desktop GIS software you could import the two data types in their appropriate formats (which you haven't specified) whether they are shapefiles or even simply tables. Then a table join can be undertaken based on attributes. By selecting the measurement times as the join fields then a table will be created where if the measurement times values are shared in both your types of data the rows will be appended to one another.